# Сервер возвращает ошибку после ajax запроса

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, сервер, form

Есть форма, я отправляю запрос с данными из формы на страницу с обработчиком(в моем случае тот же файл) и получаю ответ от сервера с ошибкой(вовод алерта с ошибкой: `error:undefined`).

```js
function call() {
  var msg = $('#comment_form').serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../blog-single.php',
    data: msg,
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, str) {
      alert("Error: " + xhr.responseCode);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="leave_comment">
  <h3 class="blog_heading_border">Leave a Comment</h3>
  <form method="POST" id="comment_form" action="javascript:void(null);" onsubmit="call()">

    <div id="comments"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input placeholder="Name" name="name" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input placeholder="Email" name="email" class="form-control" type="email">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" class="form-control"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="submit" name="do_comment" class="btn btn-primary-lg center-block comment-form_submit fa_btn_grey">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Обрабатываю данные самым примитивным образом(просто что бы получить ответ):

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

Вот скрин с консоли: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я просто пытаюсь сделать так, что бы данные введенные в форму выводились на страницу без  её перезагрузки, подскажите, в чем у меня проблема то?

Comment: Ошибка указывает, что файл скрипта не найден. Попробуйте исправить путь на скрипт: url:'blog-single.php'

Comment: @RaZik да уж, я сглупил)спасибо за помощь)